# Variable-Length Parameter Lists

Tags: c

```
/* va_arg example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void PrintLines ( char* first, ...)
{
  char* str;
  va_list vl;

  str=first;

  va_start(vl,first);

  do {
    str=va_arg(vl,char*);
    if
    printf ("%s\n",str);

     } while (str!=NULL);

  va_end(vl);
}

int main ()
{
  PrintLines ("First","Second","Third","Fourth",NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Can we call the `PrintLines` function like this `PrintLines("First","Second","Third",6,NULL);` having integer as part of the variable argument list. If yes can anyone please explain how to do that?

Comment: You tagged your code as `C++`, but code itself is pure `C`. The language does matter here, because with `C++` you'd better use variadic templates.

Comment: You can but the thing is that you call va_arg with the char * type so it will interpret 6 as a pointer to a character (or string) which will give you some problems seeing as you do printf using %s. Why not just pass the string literal "6" ?

Comment: @Lol4t0: Using features which don't exist in C is not obligatory when writing C++.  Thank you for not removing the C++ tag though.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, such kind of question confuses, because I can write safer equivalent with variadic temples with 3 lines of code, but it looks like it wouldn't fit author.

Comment: It depends on the requirements of our project ..

Comment: @Lol4t0: Yes, I understand.  But often, these kinds of questions come from people who are *trying* to learn C++, but their source of instruction is not of the highest quality, and their code happens to not use any of the non-C-compatible features of C++.  Then someone removes the C++ tag, without even asking the OP. Then the question no longer appears with the C++ filter, and so the people who would know better can't advise the asker on better options, like variadic templates.  You didn't do that, I just wanted to be sure nobody else did, without the OP's approval.

Answer (score 3):

so for your case you just would do it hardcoded, like:

```
void PrintLines ( char* first, ...)
  ...
  str1=va_arg(vl,char*);
  str2=va_arg(vl,char*);
  str3=va_arg(vl,char*);
  int4=va_arg(vl,int);

  va_end(vl);
}
```

But I think that's not what you want: You sometimes may want to call PrintLines with an integer at pos 4, and sometimes with a string. Then you have to tell it what that thing at pos 4 is, because how should this poor function find out wether 112312123 is a integer or a address of a string? 
So you have to supply some type-info to this function, maybe similar like it's done in printf and friends: The first arg contains a string describing the rest of the arguments. Maybe something like vsprintf will do a perfect job for you?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template) in C++ 11. I know it can do this, but never used it before.

Comment: Actually here it is: `auto v = { (bool)(std::cout <<args << '\n')...};`